# Textpad Regular expressions: Find and remove everything between < >

Tags: regex, textpad

I am trying to use textpad to remove all XML so I am left with the text.  If I can remove everything that falls between a < and a > then I can do it.  What is the expression what I need to use in the "Find What" box in the find and replace function in textpad?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `<` and `>` don't occur in string properties of tags, try this:

```
<[^>]*>
```

Comment: Since you're using a negated character class, you can even modify your quantifier to be possessive, which is a performance enhancement: `<[^>]++>` should work... or `<[^>]*+>`, but I doubt you have XML markup that looks like `<>content</>` so `+` is preferable to `*`.

Comment: `<[^>]□+>` is invalid in TextPad, which is not fully RegEx compliant